# How do Bran's Wargging powers work in S06E05 "The Door"?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the fifth episode of season six of *Game of Thrones*, "The Door",

> Bran is "warged" into the past, viewing a scene in Winterfell from when Hodor/Wyllis was a child.

Meanwhile,

> Whitewalkers are attacking the cave, and Hodor goes into fits similar to the last few times Whitewalkers have attacked.  Eventually, Hodor's eyes roll back, which is our visual clue that Bran has warged into his body, and he starts behaving un-Hodor-like, standing up and taking action.  It is apparent that Bran is now in control of Hodor's body.

But,

> Bran is shown to still be warging/viewing the past (is that the same power?  Is it something else?).  So he seems to be both viewing the past and controlling Hodor's body at the same time.

And then finally,

> Bran appears to - intentionally or not - also warg into young Hodor/Wyllis's body while in the past, causing the young version to seize and begin shouting the phrase heard by his older present-day self.

So what actually happened here?

> How do Bran's powers work?  Has he ever been able to warg two people at the same time, or was that only possible because they were both versions of the same people?  Has he ever warged into someone while viewing the past?  Has he ever been shown to be able to "see" himself as himself while warging someone, as he was still seeing himself as Bran while controlling Hodor?  Or was everything that happened in this episode brand new incarnations of his ability?

Comment: So many spoiler blocks.

Comment: @anaranjada I know, I'm sorry, I couldn't think of how to ask the question without them. I'd welcome any edits that make it better without spoiling anything for those who haven't seen it yet.

Comment: It's fine, and I would have no idea what to edit. I'd rather see a post awash in spoiler blocks than warnings at the top ordering people to flee for their lives if they haven't seen the episode.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's possible that we just don't know exactly what happened or how. If that's the case, maybe we will find out later on, and maybe we never will.

Comment: The really interesting thing about this is that it is one more foreshadowing that Bran can influence the past, like when he called out to his father at the Tower of Joy. (this is also foreshadowed in the books, but in that scene Ned was at Winterfell, clearning his sword *Ice* in the godswood).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont think there is a definitive cannonical answer yet. As far as I know, Bran had never warged into two things at the same time prior to this incident.

In [this interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHMTVcbvb3c), Isaac Hempstead Wright (Bran) says,

> Hodor was a totally normal kid that was screwed over by Bran.

The actors are often left in the dark about the future of their character or have a differing opinion than GRRM. However, in the absence of clear direction, I'll take what Wright says.

[Hollywood Reporter](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/game-thrones-hodor-twist-impact-896603?utm_source=twitter) also posted an article that extrapolated a bit. Obviously this isn't canon, but I post it since it contains some perspectives that hadn't originally occurred to me.

> In the final moments of "The Door," Bran's green-seeing and warging abilities crossed the streams in such a way that he wargs into Hodor and orders him to "hold the door" from an army of the dead. It gives the present Hodor his final directive, and the past Hodor the new name and limited vocabulary that would haunt him for the rest of his life.
>
> ...
>
> In Game of Thrones, Bran hopping into the past and ordering Wylis to "hold the door" always happened, resulting in the name and word "Hodor." While it's a harrowing end for such a beloved character, the implications are even more unsettling, as it confirms suspicions that Bran can indeed interact with the past, with horrific results.

Take together, the implication is that Bran was indeed warging present Hodor and past Wyllis/Hodor at the same time. Furthermore, the Bran's interference in the past is what caused Wyllis to become Hodor. Bran doesn't just view the past, his actions there can have real consequences.

Comment: my only problem with these quotes is that it wasn't Bran who ordered Hodor to "Hold the Door", it was Meera.  In fact, Bran didn't say anything to either version of Hodor/Wyllis during the entire sequence.

Comment: Another good point that hadnt occurred to me!

Comment: I don't believe that Bran forced Hodor to do anything.  We have been told by the boss greenseer (I can't recall his name) that traveling and staying too long has dangers - especially with Bran's heightened abilities.  In addition, we have heard that warging into humans is 'not right'.  It is the former that I fear has caused Wylis' seizure as Meera's commands to 'hold the door' were crossing into the time where Bran's consciousness was due to Bran's extraordinary powers allowing him to both warg and use his own senses at the same time, and somewhat communicate with the place he has traveled.

Comment: All in all, a very confusing and stressful moment for present Hodor (who was also listening to Meera shout commands).  The combination of mortal danger and Bran having to use two separate abilities at the same time without complete training (and on the same person) has led to the brain damage of Wylis and the eventual death of Hodor.  Bran is going to feel like crap when he realises.   Sorry for taking it to such a dark place.